# Security of the Libsodium function sodium_malloc() and sodium_free()

Tags: c++, libsodium

I am realizing a small program to encrypt messages.
To do this I use Libsodium.

I need to dynamically allocate sensitive data, to do this I use [Libsodium functions](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/memory_management#guarded-heap-allocations),

I read the documentation and for some doubts I inquired on intenet but of the answers I found my doubts grew, so:

`sodium_malloc()` and `sodium_free()` are functions for dynamic memory allocation and cleaning that also take care of their security?

By security, I mean that data allocated dynamically in memory cannot be read and/or overwritten by other programs that try to access the area of memory, allocated with `sodium_malloc`, that is in use by my program; and when I call `sodium_free` before freeing the memory it is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

> data allocated dynamically in memory cannot be read and/or overwritten by other programs that try to access the area of memory, allocated with sodium_malloc

Don't be ridiculous, memory is memory. Anyone with enough permissions can read and change your memory at will.

> when I call sodiu_free before freeing the memory it is overwritten

That part is true, it will get zeroed on free.

Comment: Is there no way to ensure that sensitive data in memory cannot be read?

Comment: No, anything in memory can be read by anyone with the right permissions. That's trivial to see too, put a breakpoint in your code and mouse over your magical variable in Visual Studio (or whatever debugger you use) and you'll see its contents.